# How do I add exceptions to the protection module for openpyxl?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

I am locking a sheet in excel by using:

```
ws2.protection.sheet = True
ws2.protection.enable()
```

When I do this i cannot sort/filer in that sheet. How do I add an exception so that this will be possible?

Answer (score 3):

As described in the [docs](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable) on the [protection page](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protection.html):

> Various aspects of a worksheet can also be locked by setting
>   attributes on the [`openpyxl.worksheet.protection.SheetProtection`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.protection.html#openpyxl.worksheet.protection.SheetProtection)
>   object.

Clicking on that `SheetProtection` object, will bring you to all the protection attributes you can turn on/off.

---

As for filtering, things are a little tricky. You can use the `autoFilter` attribute:

```
ws.protection.autoFilter = False
```

but this will only allow using **pre-existed filters** already applied to the file. The user will not be able to set/cancel filters. I couldn't find any official reference regarding this, but this is what I could figure out from playing with it.

It is of-course possible to set a specific filter using the [`auto_filter`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/filters.html) right before you lock:

```py
ws.auto_filter.ref = "A1:C2"
ws.protection.autoFilter = False
```

but still, the user will not be able to set a new filter, only use this one.

---

As for sorting, things get even trickier. doing a simple:

```
 ws.protection.sort = False
```

Will enable sorting. **BUT**, as stated in [this blog](https://blog.softartisans.com/2013/10/01/kb-sorting-locked-cells-in-protected-worksheets/):

> Even if Sort is enabled in the worksheet protection settings, if a
>   user attempts to sort **locked** cells when a worksheet is protected,
>   Excel throws the error *“the cell or chart you are trying to change is
>   protected and therefore read-only.”*

In addition:

> The purpose of locking a cell is to prevent a user from editing the
>   content of a cell when a worksheet is protected. This means when
>   worksheet protection is turned off, a locked cell is no different from
>   an unlocked cell. **By default, all cells in an Excel worksheet are
>   locked.**

and:

> When a cell is locked, not all worksheet protection properties operate
>   as you’d expect. 
>   [...]
>   This is because in order to use these features the affected cell’s
>   content must be changed. For example, using “Sort” does not just
>   change the order of how the cells are viewed, it actually **changes the
>   values of the cells** so that they are sorted. Due to this
>   implementation of “Sort,” this worksheet protection property **does not
>   work when the cells are locked.**

So one way I found to get around this, is:

- Select the cells you want to allow sorting and Unlock them (not `Allow Users to Edit Ranges` as detailed in the blog - This seems to get undone once you modify the protection).
- When you set the protection of the sheet, add the line:

  ```
  ws.protection.selectUnlockedCells = True
  ```

This makes sure that the cells are not locked, so can be modified (hence sorted and filtered) but because you block the selection of unlocked cells, their values can't be modified and that might serve you well.

- It is important to note that this is of course a general problem with Excel and not related for using Python. The same issues can be observed while playing around with Excel protection options, unrelated to modifying them through code.

---

As a side note, only one of `sheet = True` or `enable()` is needed. This can be seen in the [source code](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/openpyxl/worksheet/protection.html#SheetProtection.enable):

```py
def enable(self):
    self.sheet = True
```

---

So to wrap things up, a general scheme of a code could be something like:

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook("book1.xlsx")

ws = wb.active

ws.protection.enable()

ws.protection.sort = False
ws.protection.selectUnlockedCells = True

ws.auto_filter.ref = "A1:C2"
ws.protection.autoFilter = False

wb.save("book1.xlsx")
```